# Text input's border changes color only when the second wrong character is typed - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a tip calculator and I want the text input to turn red if a "non-number" is typed, and green if a number is typed.

Works good with the number. Once I type a number the border turns green, but if I type a letter, for the first letter it turns green, then only when the second letter is typed it turns red.

It happens both if the page just loaded and if there were values typed before.

I tried to change the trigger with `onkeyup` and `onkeydown`, but didn't work, and I'm pretty sure that would not be the solution anyways.

**The Snippet**

```js
function checking() {
  let hey = document.querySelector('.checkInput')
  let hello = document.querySelector('.howMuch')

  if(isNaN(hey.value)) {
    hey.style.border = '1px solid red'
  }
  else {
    hey.style.border = '1px solid green'
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label for="checkInput">How much is the check?</label>
    <input class="checkInput" onkeypress="checking()" id="checkInput" type="text"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm supposing a string has to be more than 1 character to be considered string? But that woudn't make sense. That would mean that a  single letter is considered a number

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `keyup` event, because the text is not actually inserted yet on 'keypress':

```js
function checking(e) {
  const input = document.querySelector('.checkInput')

  if(isNaN(input.value)) {
    input.style.border = '1px solid red'
  }
  else {
    input.style.border = '1px solid green'
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <label for="checkInput">Input: </label>
    <input class="checkInput" onkeyup="checking()" id="checkInput" type="text"><br>
</div>
```

Keypress lifecycle demo:

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('#test');

inp.addEventListener("keyup", log);
inp.addEventListener("keypress", log);
inp.addEventListener("keydown", log);

function log(event){
  console.log(event.type, inp.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

Comment: thank you it works, but could you explain the + in front of the variable? first time I see it. I also see that you changed the trigger to key up

Comment: `+` in front of a string is called "unary plus" and is used to transform a string to a number - read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus. Ah yeah I changed it, but it shouldn't make any difference @Mailer

Comment: thank you. actualy I removed the + and changed the trigger. with keyup and without the plus it works, whereas if I keep the plus but with keypress trigger it doesn't

Comment: Ah yeah totally my mistake. keypress is before the actual text input and keyup is after, that's why it doesn't work. You said you already tried keyup, so my thought was to explicitly tell the string to convert to a num and more or less catch the resulting Error. Well good thing its solved :) @Mailer

Comment: Updated the answer and simplified it, so that other people can follow it easier.

Comment: thank you. yes I actually tried with keyup, but maybe there was a typo and this is why it didn't work. thank again